# Ruby side-by-side error (sxstrace)

Tags: ruby, windows-10, side-by-side, ruby-2.4

**Apologies in advance for the messy question**.

I have a problem after installing Ruby 2.4.4-x64 with MYSYS2 from the site.

Running `ruby -v` from the command prompt gives this error:

```
The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is 
incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line 
sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
```

Here is the error from the event viewer:

```
Activation context generation failed for "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ruby.exe". 
Dependent Assembly ruby_builtin_dlls,type="win32",version="1.0.0.0" could not 
be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.
```

Not knowing how to use sxstrace, I decided to freshly install Ruby, but the same error persists. Some forums suggested installing `Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable (x86)` but this has no effect on my PC.

Info

1. `gem` and `irb` work if called, but `ruby -v` does not.
2. PC info - Lenovo ThinkPad T420, Windows 10 Home x64.
3. Worked fine on old laptop

Path variable (if relevant):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Windows;C:\Users\okait\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Windows;
C:\Users\okait\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin;
C:\Ruby24-x64\bin;
C:\Users\okait\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

Sidenote:

(I *may* have had to copy `ruby.exe` into the `system32` folder which was the only way for me to get it to respond in any way, otherwise the command prompt stalls and does not respond.)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZbfMC41R

Comment: have you used sxstrace? What do you see in the sxstrace.txt?

Comment: hi there, @magicandre1981 sorry for the late reply - I don't know where the log file is for Ruby, and also I don't know how to use the Sxstrace tool

Comment: my pastebin link shows how to run sxstrace

Comment: Thank you @magicandre1981, I will definitely try this when I get the time. Thanks for your patience (and perseverance)